# Powershell to replace text in multiple files in one folder

Tags: powershell, replace, file-get-contents

I am looking to replace a string of text in multiple text files. the string is the same in all of the files however the file names are different. All of the test files are in the same folder. essentially I am updating the path to a share in the logon scripts of multiple users. I do not want to do this manually as to there are hundreds of files. I want to use a `get-content -replace` to accomplish this.

Here is the code I've tried so far.

```
set pwd $filepath

for each($file in $filepath)
{ (get-content $file) -replace $find, $replace
}
```

`$filepath` is the path to a shared drive on a remote server.
`$find` is the string to replace.

I get access denied errors when executing the `get-content` cmdlt.
`$replace` is the replacement string.

Comment: Well, can you show us what you've tried?(:

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried so we can help with the code. Also some examples would help

Comment: `$old = 'new who'
$new = 'new(:'
$Path = "\\VMServer12\tablestra\"


Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Depth 3 -Filter *.txt | 
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname |
  foreach {
            (Get-Content $_).replace($old,$new) |
             Set-Content $_ 
            } 2>&1 | Out-Null -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments. I have made a few changes to the code. Now my problem is an access denied error.

Comment: Here is my code: 
# Variable Declaration
$find
$replace
$filepath

#Variable Assignment
 $find = "houfilesvr01"
 $replace = "aps.local"
 $filepath = C:\Users\jshabazz\Documents\Area51\logonscripttesting\Testfiles
 
#execution
 
 foreach($file in (gci $filepath))
  {
   (get-content $file) -replace $find, $replace |add-content $filepath -force
  }

Comment: Here is my error :
add-content : Access to the path 'C:\Users\jshabazz\Documents\Area51\logonscripttesting\Testfiles' is denied.
At C:\Users\jshabazz\Documents\Area51\logonscripttesting\Testfiles\test1.ps1:15 char:50
+ ... content $file) -replace $find, $replace |add-content $filepath -force
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\jshaba...sting\Testfiles:String) [Add-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShe

Comment: I have made sure that everyone has full control of the folder these files are in, mt execution policy is set to unrestricted. I cant figure out why PS cant access the folder that the script is being run from

Answer (score 0):

the access issue was resolved by changing the `$filepath` variable to :

```
$filepath = "C:\Users\jshabazz\Documents\Area51\logonscripttesting\Testfiles\*.*"
```

the wildcards were the key!